# Laravel: Verifying Authentication without reload

Tags: php, laravel, server-sent-events

I am working on a way to confirm when a user has logged out so that when they log out on one page, they are taken to the login page on all pages. In order to check this, I am using Server-Sent Events with a loop that looks like the following:

```
// check for new notifications every 2 seconds
$poller->loop(function ($every) use ($poller) {
    $poller->write("check", Auth::check());
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        $poller->throwError("out", "You are no longer logged in!");
    } else {
        $poller->pingNotifications();
    }
}, 2);
```

I have noticed however that laravel seems to only evaluates the `Auth::check()` on load of a page which is weird. I made this observation because the ping "check" never changes even if I logout from the page on another tab.

Is there a way around this or is this just the nature of laravel? If so, what kind of ideas come to mind when you think of checking authentication besides using AJAX.

Comment: So you just want to redirect them to the login, once their session has expired?

Comment: That is Correct @ggg

Answer (score 1):

Without using ajax (which even still would be a tad cumbersome) your only real option is to redirect the user through the logout script when logging out (this will dump the session data). From there, route all routes requiring an authenticated user through the Auth middleware and if they are not logged in they will get directed to the login page.  Laravel is great for this because you can define route 'groups' in your route file or call the middleware specifically on a method as required in the case of a controller.

Comment: So from the logout script on one tab I can have it automatically redirect the page on another tab?

Answer (score 0):

Just a direction you could take... easiest when using session database driver as laravel stores the user id in it for you...

Given each session is a record in the database... if you delete all sessions where user_id = current user id ini your /logout route, all your sessions will expire...

Comment: Session, just like Auth is no changing when just looped. It seems like these both require the page to load.

Comment: It won't change when you loop for sure, what would cause it to change? Your request establishes the session... then nothing changes until next request... so when you logout, you kill your session and any other session into which you are logged it. Polling here will do nothing as nothing will change... You must catch it in the logout route...